# 'Classic Shell' shell extension messed up explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

On a Windows 10 box, installing and uninstalling the shell extension 'Classic Shell' has left some issues behind.

Notably, attempting to use the 'New Folder' button in the explorer window downright crashes explorer, and right cliking the desktop causes a kind of 'reset' — the desktop disappears, replaced by a black screen for about a second, before coming back.

What is the likely cause of these issues, and how can they be solved?

Comment: capture a crash dump and I'll take a look at it: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: have you captured the dump?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click crashes or delays are caused by context menu handler shell extensions. To check if the ClassicShell extension (or any other) is causing the problem, use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) utility from Nirsoft.

Sort by "Type" column, disable 3rd party extensions one at a time or in a batch and restart explorer (CTRL + E) ([Source](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm))